# split a list of list that contains string

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
[["testo=text1","testo2=text2"],["testo3=text3","testo4=text4"]]
```

I want to split each element of each sublist by `"="`.

Desired result:

```
[['testo', 'text1'],['testo2', 'text2']]
```

My attempt was to iterate over each sub-list and split. But it's not working:

```
[j.split("=") for j in [i for i in splitted_params]]
```

keep getting `'list' object has no attribute 'split'` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
l = [["testo=text1","testo2=text2"],["testo3=text3","testo4=text4"]]

new_l = [inner_element.split("=") for x in l for inner_element in x]

print(new_l)
```

output:

```
[['testo', 'text1'], ['testo2', 'text2'], ['testo3', 'text3'], ['testo4', 'text4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to be clever with python list comprehensions. In my opinion, you should go for the readable solution. :)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        ["testo=text1","testo2=text2"],
        ["testo3=text3","testo4=text4"]
    ]

    for arr in data:
        for index in range( len(arr) ):
            arr[index] = arr[index].split('=')

    print(data)
```

In your expression, `[j.split("=") for j in [i for i in splitted_params]]`, the inner expression, `[i for i in splitted_params]` is evaluated first, which gives you a list. You did nothing in this list comprehension. Then, when you evaluate `[j.split("=") for j in SOME_RESULT_YOU_GOT]`, you are trying to split a list, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain.from_iterable()` to avoid the double `for` loop in the list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [["testo=text1", "testo2=text2"], ["testo3=text3", "testo4=text4"]]

[i.split('=') for i in chain.from_iterable(l)]
# [['testo', 'text1'], ['testo2', 'text2'], ['testo3', 'text3'], ['testo4', 'text4']]
```

Explanation why your solution doesn‘t work:

```
splitted_params = [["testo=text1", "testo2=text2"], ["testo3=text3", "testo4=text4"]]

print([i for i in splitted_params] == splitted_params)
# True
```

So when you use `[i for i in splitted_params]` inside your listcomp you get the same list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `[i for i in splitted_params]` this doesn't return the lists in your list of lists.
it just returns your list of lists so when you then loop through it again, it will try to split the lists in the list of lists.

so I would suggest you just do a loop in a loop like this

```
listoflists = [["testo=text1", "testo2=text2"], ["testo3=text3", "testo4=text4"]]
for i in listoflists:
    for j in i:
        print(j.split("="))
```

It may not be as pretty but it does get the job done.